# URL Routing is not working in IIS 7.0 witrh apllication pool asp.net 2.0 Classical Mode

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, iis-7, url-routing, application-pool

I have implemented the URL Routing in my projects I have followed the below article:
[URL Routing DEMO](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205221404/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/051309-1.aspx#postadlink)

This URL Routing Demo works fine in my **"IIS 7.0 with application pool asp.net 2.0 Integrated Mode"**

but not works(gives 404 error) when I have set it as  **"IIS 7.0 with application pool asp.net 2.0 Classical Mode"**

i need a configuration for IIS 7.0 with application pool configured as classic mode in asp.net 2.0 .

Please specify your configuration for above project to work(or routing to work)

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

In classic mode IIS7 you basically need this added to your config. See [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/508/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-7-integrated-pipeline/) for more info (scroll down to **Wildcard script mapping in IIS 7 classic pipeline mode**).

```
<system.webServer>
    ...
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">
      ...
      <remove name="StaticFile" />
      <add name="ASP.NET-ISAPI-2.0-Wildcard"
         path="*" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG"
         modules="IsapiModule"
         scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll"
         preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="StaticFile" 
         path="*" verb="*" 
         modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" 
         resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Read" />
    </handlers>
    ...
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I have added the given code in my web.config, after that it gives the 500 Internal server error...

Comment: Probably an error in your config, did you add it into `<system.webServer>`? Can you post what you have? Sorry just realised I gave you wrong link as well, I'll fix.

Comment: just realised in your question you refer to .net 2.0, routing is only available in 3.5 SP1 - are you using that?

Comment: You might be getting an error because of dup `staticFile`, I added a line to make sure it's removed prior to re-adding.

Comment: then why it works with "IIS 7.0 with application pool asp.net 2.0 Integrated Mode"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3323/discussion-between-askiitians-and-thecodeking)